# i want to center this navbar now its float right so i need it in the middle

Tags: html, css, nav

i want to center this navbar now its float right so i need it in the middle 
the full code is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/H5SN9/1/

thank

```
<div class="nav">           
 <ul> 
</ul>
</div>
```

css

```
.nav{
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
width: 100%;
 }
 .nav ul {
 width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
font-size: 1.5em;
font-weight: 300;
 }
```

Comment: You have to use a specific width for  `.nav` if you want it to be centered.

Comment: thank you and i have also edited the width: 100%; to 609px which equal the total of <il> widths

Answer (score 1):

Remove `float:right` from `li` and give it `display:inline-block`.

Also, remove `width:100%` from `.nav ul`, give it `display:inline-block`, this will keep its width as per its child lis.

And align center text of `.nav`

NOTE: `inline-block` elements leave white-space in between. To remove this space, use comments like:

```
<li>
    ...
</li><!--
--><li>
    ...
</li>
.nav {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:center;
}
.nav ul {
    display:inline-center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/H5SN9/2/)

Comment: thank you and i have also edited the width: 100%; to 609px which equal the total of <il> widths